# Latex in VSCode, external pdf viewer refreshes twice each time

Tags: vscode, latex-workshop

I'm using MacTex with Latex-Workshop in vscode, and Slkim as my external viewer. If I enable "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt", Skim refreshes twice per build. But if I disable autoClean then the problem disappear.

Based on my observation, seems autoClean triggers an extra change and then triggers Slim to refresh again after the aux files are deleted. How to fix this?

Latex-Workshop log:

```
[13:03:43][Extension] onDidSaveTextDocument triggered: file://%WS1%/paper.tex
[13:03:43][Builder] Auto build started on saving file: %WS1%/paper.tex .
[13:03:43][Commander] BUILD command invoked.
[13:03:43][Commander] The document of the active editor: file://%WS1%/paper.tex
[13:03:43][Commander] The languageId of the document: latex
[13:03:43][Commander] Building root file: %WS1%/paper.tex
[13:03:43][Builder] Build root file %WS1%/paper.tex
[13:03:43][Builder] outDir: %WS1% .
[13:03:43][Builder] Preparing to run recipe: latexmk.
[13:03:43][Builder] Prepared 1 tools.
[13:03:43][Builder] Recipe step 1 The command is latexmk:["--shell-escape","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-pdf","%WS1%/paper"].
[13:03:43][Builder] env: undefined
[13:03:43][Builder] root: %WS1%/paper.tex
[13:03:43][Builder] cwd: %WS1%
[13:03:43][Builder] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 93033.
[13:03:48][Parser][TexLog] Logged 5 messages.
[13:03:48][Builder] Finished a step in recipe with PID 93033.
[13:03:48][Builder] Successfully built %WS1%/paper.tex .
[13:03:48][Viewer] Call refreshExistingViewer: "%WS1%/paper.tex" .
[13:03:48][Viewer] Not found PDF viewers to refresh: undefined
[13:03:48][Cacher] Parsing .fls %WS1%/paper.fls .
[13:03:48][Cacher] Found .aux %WS1%/paper.tex from .fls %WS1%/paper.fls , parsing.
[13:03:48][Cacher] Parsed .aux %WS1%/paper.tex .
[13:03:48][Cacher] Parsed .fls %WS1%/paper.fls .
[13:03:48][Builder] Auto Clean invoked.
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Clean glob matched files {"globs":["*.aux","*.bbl","*.blg","*.idx","*.ind","*.lof","*.lot","*.out","*.toc","*.acn","*.acr","*.alg","*.glg","*.glo","*.gls","*.fls","*.log","*.fdb_latexmk","*.snm","*.synctex(busy)","*.synctex.gz(busy)","*.nav","*.vrb"],"outdir":"%WS1%"} .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Ignore folder glob patterns with globstar:  .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Cleaning file %WS1%/paper.out .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Cleaning file %WS1%/paper.log .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Cleaning file %WS1%/paper.fls .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Cleaning file %WS1%/paper.fdb_latexmk .
[13:03:48][Cleaner] Cleaning file %WS1%/paper.aux .
```

My VScode settings:

```
// AutoSave
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
// Latex
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": \[
{
"name": "latexmk",
"command": "latexmk",
"args": \[
"--shell-escape", // added arg to default
"-synctex=1",
"-interaction=nonstopmode",
"-file-line-error",
"-pdf",
"%DOC%"
\]
},
{
"name": "pdflatex",
"command": "pdflatex",
"args": \[
"--shell-escape", // added arg to default
"-synctex=1",
"-interaction=nonstopmode",
"-file-line-error",
"%DOC%"
\]
},
{
"name": "bibtex",
"command": "bibtex",
"args": \[
"%DOCFILE%"
\]
}
\],
"latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt",
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.command": "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline",
"latex-workshop.view.outline.commands": \[
\],
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot say anything about Visual Studio Code here, but to get stuff like references right, at least two runs of the PDF build process are required. I assume that LaTeX Workshop/the invoked `latexmk` does this, leaving you with two refresh calls. `autoClean` seems to basically remove all auxiliary files which are generated in the first run of LaTeX - with this option disabled, LaTeX will just re-use the previous auxiliary files in the next run.